# Check if github-cli is logged in

Tags: bash, git-bash, github-cli

I'm working in a bash script using the github cli to create some repos under some conditions but for that I first need to check if the user has the cli installed (and I got that check working) and if it is logged in. gh-cli provides a function `gh auth status` for that, but I can't use its return to check if the user is logged in.
There are two possible outputs:

```
You are not logged into any GitHub hosts. Run gh auth login to authenticate.
```

or

```
    github.com
  ✓ Logged in to github.com as <username> (oauth_token)
  ✓ Git operations for github.com configured to use ssh protocol.
  ✓ Token: *******************
```

So my first try was to check if there is "not logged" inside that string with:

```
if [[ $(gh auth status) =~ "not logged" ]] ;
then
    echo "Not logged" ;
    exit 1
fi
#run script
```

But I had no success. I tried also using grep -oP and sed but then I realized that somehow i can't get the output as a string

Anyone has any suggestions on how to check or fix this?

Comment: `gh auth status` emits its output to stderr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the *exit status* to determine the success/failure of the installed and logged-in checks:

1. check it's installed:

   ```bash
   if ! command -v gh >/dev/null 2>&1; then
       echo "Install gh first"
       exit 1
   fi
   ```
2. check auth

   ```bash
   if ! gh auth status >/dev/null 2>&1; then
       echo "You need to login: gh auth login"
       exit 1
   fi
   ```